# SimpleAdapter on HashMap does not work properly

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have a JSON like this:

```
 [{"message":"Hello","id":1,"name":"Hello"},{"message":"James","id":2,"name":"Smith"}]
```

Which I use to populate an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` in order to diplay the json's items into a ListView. 
This is the code I am currently using:

```
   private void createListView(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < json.length() ; i++){
            try{
                JSONObject temp = json.getJSONObject(i);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name", temp.getString("name"));
                map.put("message", temp.getString("message"));
                data.add(map);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String[] from = new String[]{"name", "message"};
        int to[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("Debug", json.toString());

    }
```

This code almost work, but not the way I would. It display only the *name* field.

How can I modify it in order to display both the *message* and *name* field ?

Comment: it displays only the name field because you give it 2 items to display and you only declare 1 position to display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It display only the message field.

Because using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for row which contain only on TextView with `android.R.id.text1` id

> How can I modify it in order to display both the message and name
>   field ?

Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` as layout for rows and change `to` array :

```
int to[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
int to[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
```

to

```
int to[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Error in this line

```
int to[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
```

Here you are mention only one control . I guess that is for message. You need to add another one control for `Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Use "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2" instead of "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                 this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                 mCursor,     // Pass in the cursor to bind to.
                 new String[] {People.NAME, People.COMPANY}, // Array of cursor columns to bind to.
                 new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});  // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those columns.

         // Bind to our new adapter.
         setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleAdapter playlistadapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), songsList, R.layout.file_view,
                new String[] { "songTitle","songAlbum", "songartist","songPath" }, new int[] { R.id.checkTextView, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4 });

playlistadapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder(){
    boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation){
            if(view.getId () == R.id.songartist){
                view.setText("("+textRepresentation+")");
            }
    }
});
```